# recurrent events-Probability of even number of successes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

Let E be the event of an even number of successes.

$u_n$:Probability of E occurring at the nth trial not necessarily for the first time

$f_n$:Probability of E occurring at the nth trial for the first time

Let U(x) and F(x) be the corresponding probability generating functions and from that we have the equation $$U(x)=1/(1-F(x))$$
I first wrote a recurrence formula $u_n=p(1-u_{n-1})+qu_{n-1}$

By solving this I got $$U(x)=px/[(1-x)(1-(q-p)x)]$$

Intuitively I feel $F(x)$ should be $p^2x^2/(1-qx)^2$ since this event can be taken as the sum of two geometric random variables. However this is not what I get from the $U(x)$ that I have computed. Did I do something wrong? Any assistance will be very helpful to me. Thanks alot

EDIT: In an answer I saw $u_n$ taken as $[1-(q-p)^{n-1}]p$ which gives results in the $F(x)$ of sum of two random geometric variables but I do not know how this $u_n$ was constructed

Comment: I made an edit to the recurrent formula sorry

Comment: What probability are you trying to compute? That the $n^{th}$ trial results in even number of successes?

Comment: $u_n$ is defined in that way isn't it not?

Comment: @gar I made an additional comment in the question

Comment: I interpreted $u_n$ as probability for which we must see the even number of successes occuring at least twice, and the $n^{th}$ trial must be a success. E.g. If $1$ stands for success and $0$ for failure, then for 7 trials, $0101101$ is valid, but $0101110$ is not. $0000101$ is also not valid since even successes have occured only once. The probability I get for that is: $$\mathbb{P} = \frac{p}{2}\cdot \left(1-(q-p)^{n-1}-2\,(n-1)\,p\,q^{n-2}\right)$$ I can't really post an answer without getting a clear question. Post the complete question!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_n$ be the probability that $n$ Bernoulli trials result in an 
*even  number of successes*.
This occurs if an initial failure is followed by an even number of successes, or an initial success
is followed by an odd number of successes. Therefore $u_0=1$ and for $n\geq 1$
$$u_n=q u_{n-1}+p(1-u_{n-1}).$$
Multiplying by $s^n$ and adding over $n$ we see that the generating function
satisfies
$$U(s)=1+qsU(s)+ps(1-s)^{-1}-psU(s)$$
or
$$2U(s)=[1-s]^{-1}+[1-(q-p)s]^{-1}.$$
Expanding the right hand side using geometric series we find that the coefficients
satisfy $$u_n={1\over 2}+{(q-p)^n\over 2}.$$

**Reference:** This answer is  taken practically  verbatim from Chapter XI, section 4, page 277 of *An introduction to probability theory and its applications (1st edition)* by William Feller.

Comment: Thanks I also have seen this in Feller but I had completely forgotten about it. Do you think the way you have defined $u_n$ is the same as the question requires. Because it should occur right at the nth trial

Comment: My $u_n$ is the probability that there are an even number of successes among the first $n$ trials. I assume that this is also what you mean, perhaps you could clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do by using a Markov chain:

\begin{align*}
  A &= \begin{pmatrix}
q & p & 0 \\
0 & q & p \\
q & p & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Answer will be the third column of the first row in $A^n$, and the generating function for all entries can be obtained directly from the matrix by computing
\begin{align*}
  \left(I-x\, A\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}

Thus, the gf for the required entry is:
\begin{align*}
  G(x) &= -\frac{p^{2} x^{2}}{{\left(p^{2} - q^{2}\right)} x^{2} + 2 \, q x - 1}
\end{align*}
and by partial fractions,
\begin{align*}
  G(x) &= \frac{p^2}{q-p}+\frac{p}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{\left(q-p\right)\left(1-(q-p)\, x\right)}\right)
\end{align*}
Hence, the solution for $u_n$ is given by $[x^n]$, which is 
\begin{align*}
  u_n &= \frac{p}{2}\left(1-(q-p)^{n-1}\right)
\end{align*}

### Update

We can obtain the recurrence using the markov chain as:

\begin{align*}
  u_n &= p\, v_{n-1} \\
  v_n &= p\, \left(u_{n-1}+w_{n-1}\right)+q\, v_{n-1} \\
  w_n &= q\, \left(u_{n-1}+w_{n-1}\right) \\
  u_1 &= 0 \\
  v_1 &= p \\
  w_1 &= q \\
  u_2 &= p^2 \\
  v_2 &= 2pq \\
  w_2 &= q^2 \\
\end{align*}
$u_n$ is the required answer.

$w_n$ gives the probability of even number of successes, but not exactly at the $n^{th}$ trial.

$v_n$ is for the odd number of successes.